# The best way to check selector in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
doc.select(".main li").last().remove();
```

This is working good if `.main li` exists, but if it doesn't exist, then this my application crashes.

How can i check if `.main li` exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per JSoup API for [Document](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) and [Element.html#select(java.lang.String)‌](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select(java.lang.String)%E2%80%8C)​, `doc.select(String)` method returns [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html). So you can check for `el.size()` to see if it has any elements before deleting the last item.

```
Elements elements = doc.select(".main li");
if(elements.size() > 0){
   elements.last().remove();
}
```

or you can check if the `last` element is not `null` before removing it:

```
Element element = doc.select(".main li").last();
    if(element != null){
       element.remove();
    }
```